# Обновление QTextEdit при добавлении элементов

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qtimer, qtextedit

При добавлении новых элементов в `QTextEdit` у меня крашится окно с программой или же зависает на время, и потом отвисает с уже добавленными всеми элементами.

Как это можно обойти?

```
import time
...


text = QTextEdit()

ted = "ted"
dev = "dev"

text.append(ted)
time.sleep(2)
text.append(dev)
time.sleep(3)
...
```

Comment: Использовать pyqtsignal

Comment: `sleep` блокирует текущий поток, в котором было вызвано, а GUI работает в главном потоке, поэтому это вызывает фризы. `sleep` можно использовать в отдельном потоке, например, питоничий `Thread` или `QThread`, но не для виджетов, а для логики, причем работающей через механизм сигналов-слотов. Для кода из вашего вопроса можно использовать `QTimer`

Answer (score 2):

Забудьте про `time.sleep`, это блокирует интерфейс.

Для примера вы можете использовать `QTimer`.
`Класс QTimer` предоставляет повторяющиеся и одиночные таймеры.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import  *
from PyQt5.QtGui import  *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.myList = [ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", ]

        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.textEdit.insertPlainText("Обновление QTextEdit при добавлении элементов.\n")
        self.btn = QPushButton("Старт обновлений")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.onClick)

        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)        
        self.layout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn)

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.handleTimeout)

    def onClick(self):
        self.myListLen = len(self.myList)
        self.btn.setText("Выполнятся обновления, ожидайте...")
        self.btn.setEnabled(False)
        self.timer.start()

    def handleTimeout(self):  
        if self.myListLen:
            self.textEdit.append(self.myList[-self.myListLen])
            self.myListLen -= 1
        else:
            self.textEdit.append("---------------------------")
            self.btn.setText("Старт обновлений")
            self.btn.setEnabled(True)
            self.timer.stop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    a_window = Window()
    a_window.resize(500, 300)
    a_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @sheviv что не так?